# Calculate a mean for cases that responded to a minimum number of items in Stata?

Tags: stata

In SPSS, you can calculate means for cases that responded to a minimum number of questions. Some example SPSS syntax would be:

COMPUTE variable_new = MEAN.4(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7).

This generates a new variable (i.e., variable_new) only for cases that had a value present for 4 or more of the array x1 - x7. That's what the .4 is doing in the command, setting a minimum number of responses before the command will run for a case.

Is there any way that I can do the equivalent in Stata?